# How to setup associate domain for iOS app where its allows open link with # value

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-universal-links, associated-domains

There is one link for email authentication. So link from my specified domain have emailAuth value than its should be open in app else it should be open in browser.

But issue is

If link have # value
`https://webdomain/#/emailAuth/<tokenvalue>`
then It's not opening in my app.

But If link not have # value than its open in my app
`https://webdomain/emailAuth/<tokenvalue>`

Configuration

I have setup associate domain for iOS application.

Where I have add capability for associate domain with value `applink:webdomain`

I have also uploaded apple-app-site-association file to server

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "teamID.bundleID",
                "paths": [
                {
                    "/": "/emailAuth/*",
                    "comment": "Matches any URL with a path that starts with /emailAuth/*."
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything after the # is the anchor; you can specify an anchor match in your site association file

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you for response. Can you give sample patten. because I tried `"/": "/#/emailAuth/*"` and `"/": "/?/emailAuth/*",` but It will open all links to my app from given domain. And want to open link with `emailAuth` match.

Comment: You would want something like `"#":"/emailAuth/*"` to match on the fragment